# Performance with if statement

Tags: if-statement

Very simple question that suprisingly has no aswers in Google Search & also here.

This question applies to any file/code: PHP, JS etc.

- Let say there's dynamic webpage, it has footer.php, header.php &
  content.
- Content has 5 buttons which switch layout of content via jQuery.
- Every layout is wrapped inside `if` statement & has 1000 lines of `PHP` &
  `HTML`.

Now if only one layout is active (`if(true)`) & rest are `false`, does & if yes: **how much performance impact does it have *besides file size*?** Am I safe to use this practice & not worry about stuff in `if` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how much performance impact does it have besides file size?

None, apart from checking the condition. It doesn't matter if you put 10 or 100 lines in an if, if it isn't executed, there is no performance to worry about in that regard.

> Am I safe to use this practice & not worry about stuff in if statement?

Yes, but generally, if you have that many lines in an if or else statement, that is a sign of bad design.

Comment: @112 correct. That would be better, splitting code into multiple files that each have their responsibility is better than putting everything the same file

Comment: Put everything that belongs together in the same file, everything that doesn't should be in another file. There is no practical limit on how many lines your file is allowed to have. If you have a good reason to have 1000 lines in your file, don't worry about it